# Copy entire Excel row from one worksheet to another based on 4 cell specific critera

Tags: excel, vba

Basically what I'm trying to do in workbook sheet `RAWinsightly` is this:

- If the row is blank: don't copy.
- If Column J contains the word "Commercial" in it: copy the row unless column K also contains the words "lost" or "abandoned".

The code I've been able to figure out works great for the first two but I can't for the life of me figure out how to add the column K stuff.

```
Sub copyJobs()
  Dim r1
  Dim r2
  Dim r3

  r1 = 1
  r2 = 1
  r3 = 1

  While Sheets("RAWInsightly").Range("A" & LTrim(Str(r1))) <> ""
    If Sheets("RAWInsightly").Range("J" & LTrim(Str(r1))) = "Commercial" Then
      Sheets("RAWInsightly").Range(LTrim(Str(r1)) & ":" & LTrim(Str(r1))).Copy
      Sheets("RAWCommercial").Range("A" & LTrim(Str(r2))).PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
      r2 = r2 + 1
    End If
    If Sheets("RAWInsightly").Range("J" & LTrim(Str(r1))) = "failed" Then
      Sheets("RAWInsightly").Range(LTrim(Str(r1)) & ":" & LTrim(Str(r1))).Copy
      Sheets("RAWhousing").Range("A" & LTrim(Str(r3))).PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
      r3 = r3 + 1
    End If
    r1 = r1 + 1
  Wend
End Sub
```

Comment: Search the Excel VBA help for "and".  The third hit (in my copy anyway) is the page on the And operator which should tell you all you need to know.

Comment: Also, you can use e.g. `.Cells(r1,1)` (row & column numbers) instead of `.Range("A" & LTrim(Str(r1)))`, and `.Rows(r1)` instead of `.Range(LTrim(Str(r1)) & ":" & LTrim(Str(r1)))` which will make your code faster and more readable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Sub copyJobs()
  Dim r1
  Dim r2
  Dim r3
  Dim shtSrc as Worksheet
  Dim tmp, tmp2

  r1 = 1
  r2 = 1
  r3 = 1

  Set shtSrc = Sheets("RAWInsightly")

  While len(shtSrc.Cells(r1, "A").Value) > 0

      'performing case-insensitive checks...
      tmp = LCase(shtSrc.Cells(r1, "J").Value)
      tmp2 = LCase(shtSrc.Cells(r1, "K").Value)

      If tmp = "commercial" And tmp2 <> "lost" And tmp2 <> "abandoned" Then
          shtSrc.Rows(r1).Copy Sheets("RAWCommercial").Cells(r2, "A")
          r2 = r2 + 1
      End If

      If tmp = "failed" Then
          shtSrc.Rows(r1).Copy Sheets("RAWhousing").Cells(r3, "A")
          r3 = r3 + 1
      End If

      r1 = r1 + 1

  Wend

End Sub
```

Comment: I also got this answer:
 While Sheets("RAWInsightly").Range("A" & LTrim(Str(r1))) <> ""
  If Sheets("RAWInsightly").Range("J" & LTrim(Str(r1))) = "Commercial" And _
     Sheets("RAWInsightly").Range("K" & LTrim(Str(r1))) <> "Lost" And _
     Sheets("RAWInsightly").Range("K" & LTrim(Str(r1))) <> "Abandoned" Then
      Sheets("RAWInsightly").Range(LTrim(Str(r1)) & ":" & LTrim(Str(r1))).Copy
      Sheets("RAWCommercial").Range("A" & LTrim(Str(r2))).PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
      r2 = r2 + 1
            
      End If